# How do I send multiple 32 byte strings to I2C master?

Tags: arduino, i2c

I have multiple variable length strings which do not exceed 32 bytes each which need to be sent via I2C between 2 Arduino Nanos. I use # to terminate each string. I can successfully send and receive the first string, but for the life of me I can't figure out how to send the succeeding strings. The samples I am testing with look like this:

```
    String answer = "12345,123.4,50.6,12345#";
    String answerV = "4.10,4.15,4.13,4.05,4.18,0#";
```

Master Code

```
    #include <Wire.h> 
    int esc = 0;
    int throttle = 80;    

    void setup() {
    Wire.begin();
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Serial.println("I2C Master ready!");
    esc = throttle * 100 / 180;
    }

    void loop() {
      delay(500);
      Serial.println("Receive data");
      Wire.requestFrom(9,32);
      String response = "";
      Serial.println(Wire.available());  
      while (Wire.available()) 
      {
        char b = Wire.read();
        response += b;
      }
      String dataString = response;
      int hashIndex = dataString.indexOf('#');
      String SportData = dataString.substring(0, hashIndex);
      Serial.println(SportData);

      String SDdata = String (esc) + "," + String(SportData);
      Serial.println(SDdata);
    }
```

Slave Code

```
    #include <Wire.h>

    byte ANSWERSIZE= 22;

    String answer = "12345,123.4,50.6,12345#";
    String answerV = "4.10,4.15,4.13,4.05,4.18,0#";

    void setup() {
      Wire.begin(9);
      Wire.onRequest(requestEvent); // data request from Master
      Serial.begin(115200);
      Serial.println("I2C Slave ready!");
      ANSWERSIZE = answer.length();
    }

    void requestEvent() {
      byte response[ANSWERSIZE];
      for (byte i=0;i<ANSWERSIZE;i++) 
      {
        response[i] = (byte)answer.charAt(i);
      }
      Wire.write(response,sizeof(response));
    }

    void loop() {
      delay(50);
    }
```

Can someone please show me how this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

A simple idea is to keep track of the number of times `requestEvent()` is called, and use that to decide what to send back to the **master**.

---

Here is the code *(n.b. I took the liberty to optimise it a bit)*:

**Master:**

```cpp
#include <Wire.h> 

/**
 * globals
 */

int esc = 0;
int throttle = 80;    
char i2c_buffer[33];

/**
 * setup & loop
 */

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Wire.begin();

    esc = throttle * 100 / 180;
    i2c_buffer[32] = '\0';

    Serial.println("I2C Master ready!");
}

void loop()
{
    delay(500);

    Wire.requestFrom(9, 32);

    for (byte i = 0; i < 32 && Wire.available(); ++i)
    {
        i2c_buffer[i] = Wire.read();

        if (i2c_buffer[i] == '#') {
            i2c_buffer[i] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }

    Serial.print(esc);
    Serial.print(',');
    Serial.println(i2c_buffer);
}
```

**Slave:**

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>

/**
 * globals
 */

const byte DATA_SIZE = 2;
String data[DATA_SIZE] = {
    "12345,123.4,50.6,12345#",
    "4.10,4.15,4.13,4.05,4.18,0#"
};

/**
 * setup & loop
 */

void setup()
{
    Serial.begin(115200);
    Wire.begin(9);
    Wire.onRequest(requestEvent); // data request from Master

    Serial.println("I2C Slave ready!");
}

void loop()
{
    delay(50);
}

/**
 * help functions
 */

void requestEvent()
{
    static byte req_number = 0;

    Wire.write(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(data[req_number].c_str()),
               data[req_number].length());

    req_number = (req_number + 1) % DATA_SIZE;
}
```

---

***Note:*** I don't have two Arduino devices, so I could not test this code. If you spot some bugs, report back and I'll fix them.

Comment: Your method works a treat. Now I just need to work it into the main sketches. Thanks so much for the help (and the optimization).

Comment: I'm trying to do this in stages as my existing master/slave are really complicated. I incorporated the code you provided in my slave and used the master you provided. When I use the test data array you provided it works just fine. Once I use an array that I fill with real time data the master gets the first array entry data[0] from the slave, but data[1] doesn't show.

Here is how I defined the array:
         const byte DATA_SIZE = 2; 
         String data[DATA_SIZE];

Comment: @RogerMcClurg just open a new question with a new code example, possibly removing irrelevant stuff again.. this question is already solved, though the answer is not accepted, so it's not the right place to discuss new issues :)

Comment: Old, post, but I'm taking a chance anyhow, two quick questions. Why is the size of the buffer 33 instead of 32?   And is the variable name "buffer" picked for a specific reason? This turns orange in the Arduino IDE, so it seems to be a keyword of some kind, and the code still works if I rename it to something else like i2cBuffer.

Comment: @HKrg AFAIK, buffer isn't an Arduino or C++ keyword, but I admit that I might be wrong about this. Renaming the variable is just fine. Arduino developers sometimes forget that a C string requires an extra terminator byte `\0` at the end. I wasn't sure whether OP had included this in his calculation when he said that the strings would be at most `32` bytes long, so I simply increased the size of the buffer by one to provide a safe-by-design solution.